# New bathroom fan has a 2 prong plug. Old fan was straight wired. How do I convert?

Tags: exhaust-fan

My new exhaust fan has a 2 prong plug, my old fan was straight wired so I don't have a receiver. How do I convert to straight wire?

Comment: What make/model fan?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Can you post the instructions that came with the fan?

Comment: Nutone model C350BN * C370BN

Comment: The instructions just explain how to install the fan into the ceiling. The only comment about wiring says, "plug in the motor".

Comment: There are 2 separate wires which are wired into the plug. Without cutting the plug off I can't tell if there's any difference between the two.  The coating is gray on both.

Comment: Which side of the plug has a wider prong? That side is supposed to be neutral, while the narrower one is hot.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up your fan and this is a picture of it...

[image]

It sounds like you just have some romex wire hanging from the ceiling and no outlet to plug the fan into. The wire you see is called romex. This is a large white cable with three wires inside it, Black, white and a naked copper ground wire. These wires should already be stripped but you might want to cut off about 6 more inches of the romex casing to give you some extra room for the ground wire. You can clip off and re-strip the black and white wires, as they will be too long. Cut off the existing plug on the new fan. You will need to strip the wires back. Attach the two wires from the fan to the black and the neutral wires of the romex using wire nuts. That is an Supco SM55OP2 motor equivalent, so both blades on the plug will be the same size. Polarity doesn't matter on these. Finally, attach the ground wire to the frame of the fan with a screw in the provided screw hole. You can also use a self-tapping screw if you have one. Here is a diagram to help you...

[image]

Comment: Ah, so you're making the NM-to-cordage splice inside the fan housing I take it?

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt 135 of these fan motors this way in our hotel.